# Targeting first TD but not in 1st row w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to add css to the first column of the the table, all but in the first row.

Can I do something like: **$(".myTbl tr td:not(:nth-child(1))").css(**...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More like:

```
$('.myTbl tr:not(:first) td:first').css( ... )
```

That is, the first td in each row which is not the first row in a table but only in tables with the class `myTbl`.  You may want to also specify whether you're considering header rows as distinct from body rows.  If you have them separated into header/body sections and only want the body rows you can get that with.

```
$('.myTbl tbody tr td:first').css( ... )
```

Note: I'm not addressing nested tables with this.  If you have nested tables you'll probably want to be more explicit, using direct children rather than ancestor/descendant relationships.

```
$('.myTbl > tbody > tr > td:first').css( ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you ignoring the first row because it is a header row? Is it possible to put that first row in a  and the add your css to rows inside ?

Answer (score 0):

You could put your first row in a `<thead>`, then just target the first `<tr>` in your `<tbody>`.

```
<table class="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Something</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

$(".mytable tbody tr td:first").css("something", "else");
```